# postgres left join not returning working as expected

Tags: postgresql

Hi I am using the following postgres code to join 2 tables

```
  select  m.object_id, 
c.state_name as state,
upper(c.county) as county,
LTRIM(substring(m.reference,17,2),'0') ||'-'|| LTRIM( 
 substring(m.reference,6,3),'0')|| substring(m.reference,10,1)|| '-'|| 
 LTRIM(substring(m.reference,11,3),'0')||substring(m.reference,15,1), 
                 (st_area(st_transform(m.geom,2163))*0.000247105)::decimal(10,1),
st_transform(m.geom,4267),
LTRIM(substring(m.reference,17,2),'0') ||'-'|| LTRIM( 
 substring(m.reference,6,3),'0')|| substring(m.reference,10,1)|| '-'|| 
 LTRIM(substring(m.reference,11,3),'0')||substring(m.reference,15,1), 
st_transform(st_centroid(m.geom),4267),
null, 
json_build_object('reference',m.reference),
m.source

from grid.merged_input m
left join grid.counties c on 
st_intersects(c.geom, st_transform(m.geom,4267))
```

the values of c.state_name and c.county are all nulls even though the counties table has non null values. Can someone please help me with what is wrong with the postgres code above. I am using some GIS functions here. But I think the problem is with the postgres code itself.

Thanks!

Comment: do an inner join on grid.merged_input and grid.counties to check if st_intersects(c.geom, st_transform(m.geom,4267))  returns anything -- that way you'll have a better idea where the problem is

Comment: Julia, thank you so much for your reply. I performed an inner join and it works fine with that. Why is left join not working then? I still do not understand.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? If not, could you post the results of the query with the inner join, and results of the query above?